# Display only items that match specifics creterias

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am working on a touristic application, I fetch items from firestore Firebase and display them on the screen. these items are activities data.

I want to filtre these data and arrange them by category, so I am looking for a way to display only the items that has some creterias.

So I want to disply under every category title, the activity that has the same category as the same of the title. Below the model of my data and what I have done so far.

- **Model**

```
class Activity {
  final String category;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String name;
  final String organizer;
  final String organizerLocation;

  Activity({
    required this.category,
    required this.description,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.name,
    required this.organizer,
    required this.organizerLocation,
  });
}
```

- **The code to set categories**

```
class _CategoryTitleWidgetState extends State<CategoryTitleWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final activities = Provider.of<List<Activity>?>(context);
    print(activities.runtimeType);
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount:
              activities?.length, //destinations.length, //cities?.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            Activity activity = activities![index];
            return Column(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      activity.category,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          letterSpacing: 1.5),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => print('see all'),
                      child: Text(
                        'VOIR TOUT',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            letterSpacing: 1.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              ActivitiesInsideCategoryWidget(
                  activities: activities),
            ]);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

- **The code to display activities**

```
class ActivitiesInsideCategoryWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Activity> activities;
  String category;
  ActivitiesInsideCategoryWidget(
      {required this.activities, required this.category});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300.0,
      child: new ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: activities.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              width: 210.0,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 15.0,
                    child: Container(
                        height: 120.0,
                        width: 200.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                activities[index].organizer,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    letterSpacing: 1.2),
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your activities list with `where` method for `Iterable` :

```
var relatedActivities = activities.where((activity) => activity.category == categoryName);
```

This will return a list that contains all the activities that have `categoryName` as category.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html

Comment: It worked, thank's for your answer